# Array modifier apply. Keep objects and origin point

Tags: modifiers

Is there any way to apply array modifier but with making each object separated and with right origin straight away?

Here is the problem. Each my object (flower) contains different parts (petals, stem etc) which are not connected. So if I apply modifier and then do 'Separate by Loose Parts' it divides not my flowers but each part of it. And also I loose origin point. So I need to join together all parts of the flower and set origin point as well for each. And I have about 30 flowers so it's not very effective at all...

So I hope anyone can tell me better and faster way.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible with the array modifier. You could always consider the Copy-Paste technique.

Comment: That's a shame but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain a set of separate objects from an Array Modifier (or other method) and keep their rotation and scale?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187148/how-to-obtain-a-set-of-separate-objects-from-an-array-modifier-or-other-method)

Comment: Funny I used it for delphinium flowers too.

Comment: @SteakOverflow That's great! Probably you could create a plugin from it so it'll be easy to use?